# Wordpress - get a child pages Featured Image source URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below on the parent page of a WordPress site. This page pulls the content from the children pages to display in summary format on it. What I am missing is the code on how to pull the FEATURED IMAGE URL from the child page. The title and content are being pulled nicely. Any ideas?

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <?php
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `the_post_thumbnail();` to retrieve the featured image. Refer to this [Featured Image Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) for further customization

So the modified code will be:

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> // Gets the featured image

    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php
}   
?>
```